# Woocommerce Checkout isn’t working properly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have just updated to the latest version of WordPress and woocommerce. Now the Checkout isn’t working properly.
You can add items to the cart, input your shipping details, but you can’t click either the terms & conditions button or Proceed to Paypal button. They seem to be greyed out or something like that.
WooCommerce 3.2.6
WordPress 4.9.1 running AVADA - theme, but trying to fix the problem I changed it to Twenty Seventeen
I Have also disabled and enaled pluggins, but The problem is still there- Any idea?
Thanks. Happy New Year
Alexandra

Comment: You should need also to update Avada to its last version and check if everything is correct in backend woocommerce => status…

Comment: Hey, you need to provide more details, such as website url, is there any console errors and etc. We can try to guess, what can be the problem, but it'll be a shot in the dark